How to fetch the Created_Date_Time__c field from Salesforce into Tableau?
I am connecting salesforce object directly to tableau prep using custom sql in tableau prep because i want to limit the data while gettiing it from the objects but i'm unable to fetch the fields which have names similar to this-'Created_Date_Time__c'. How to fetch this fields ?..
I tried almost everything.

Please provide enough information to make a minimal reproduceable example. Saying "I tried almost everything" does not tell any of us what you actually tried.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Be sure that the 'Created_Date_Time__c' field is available and accessible to the Salesforce user credentials you are using. Permissions or field-level security may restrict Tableau Prep from accessing specific fields.
If you still having problem try to run this code:
SELECT "Created_Date_Time__c"
FROM "Account__c"

This can help identify whether the problem is with the query syntax or how Tableau Prep handles field names.
